# Javascript: How to Save Image with a particular filename instead of download.png

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, canvg

I am trying to download the file as helloWorld.png but it always saves as download.png.

Can you help me identify what i am missing?

```
var $container = $('#svg-container'),
        // Canvg requires trimmed content
    content = $container.html().trim(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
    // Draw svg on canvas
    canvg(canvas, content);
    // Change img be SVG representation
    var theImage =  canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    $('#svg-img').attr('src', theImage);



function downloadWithName(uri, name) {

    function eventFire(el, etype){
        if (el.fireEvent) {
            (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
            evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
            el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    }

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    eventFire(link, "click");

}

downloadWithName(theImage, "helloWorld.png")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shanthisivanesan/a2FLx/22/

Comment: have you considered html5 download="filename.ext"

Comment: I have to do this programaticaly as in my jsfiddle example where I create the anchor tag dynamically. Can you let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Seems to work with base64 directly -> **http://jsfiddle.net/W48wQ/**, so I'm guessing it has something to do with whatever `canvg()` does and how the base64 is retrieved. Do you wait for the canvas to load etc ?

Comment: in my case I am converting an svg to canvas and then doing it. Even csv also does not work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/shanthisivanesan/a2FLx/21/

Comment: well, download is an attribute not unlike src. `$('#svg-img').attr('src', theImage).attr('download', filename);` - i see you have link.download there so my comment is useless. however, you're loading jquery. why not use it in this function as well?

Comment: I tried , it does not help

Comment: Must be problem with Firefox, I also can't get the jsfiddle working, however it works in chrome

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery code, it works on the latest Firefox, (where **uri** is the datauri and **name** is the image filename)

```
$('<a>',{
    type: "submit",
    download: name,
    href: uri,
    id: 'download_link'
}).appendTo('body');


$('a#download_link')[0].click();
```